# How to use collect and include for multidimensional array

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]
@student_ids = [1,2,3]
```

I want to replace elements in `array1` that are included in `@student_ids` with `'X'`. I want to see:

```
[['X','X','X',4,5],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]
```

I have code that is intended to do this:

```
array1.collect! do |i| 
  if i.include?(@student_ids) #
    i[i.index(@student_ids)] = 'X'; i # I want to replace all with X
  else
    i
  end
end
```

If `@student_ids` is `1`, then it works, but if `@student_ids` has more than one element such as `1,2,3`, it raises errors. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean your input by, `array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14]]
`

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry

Comment: @Jay Using the notation `@student_ids = 1,2,3` is rarely seen, and is not reader friendly. Please use the more standard notation `@student_ids = [1,2,3]`. I have already edited to do so.

Comment: What you mean is, "I want to replace elements *of elements* in `array1` that are included in `@student_ids`. Sloppy statements bring nothing but trouble in the profession of coding. Be precise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's faster to use a hash or a set than to repeatedly test  `[1,2,3].include?(n)`.

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]
ids = [1,2,3]
```

**Use a hash**

```
h = ids.product(["X"]).to_h
  #=> {1=>"X", 2=>"X", 3=>"X"}
arr.map { |a| a.map { |n| h.fetch(n, n) } }
  #=> [["X", "X", "X", 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html).

**Use a set**

```
require 'set'

ids = ids.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
arr.map { |a| a.map { |n| ids.include?(n) ? "X" : n } }
  #=> [["X", "X", "X", 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Replace both `map`s with `map!` if the array is to be modified in place (mutated).

Comment: For mutating, it is sufficient to use one `map!` (outer `each`, inner `map!` or outer `map!`, inner `map`)

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej, true, but `each/map!`has the disadvantage that the modified array is not returned and `map!/map` creates unneeded temporary arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each_with_index` and replace the item you want:

```
array1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]
@student_ids = [1,2,3]

array1.each_with_index do |sub_array, index|
  sub_array.each_with_index do |item, index2|
    array1[index][index2] = 'X' if @student_ids.include?(item)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `@student_ids = 1,2,3` ? Does it execute properly?

Comment: @ray I was wondering about that too, but it ts actually a shorthand for `@student_ids = [1,2,3]`. Try it. Although, it is doubtful that the OP or Roc intended that.

Comment: @sawa, my bad :|

Comment: @ray thanks for mentioning it; I fixed it in the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try following, (taking @student_ids = [1, 2, 3])

```
array1.inject([]) { |m,a| m << a.map { |x| @student_ids.include?(x) ? 'X' : x } }

# => [["X", "X", "X", 4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage to using `inject` (aka `reduce`) instead of `map`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland oops, I just noticed it. Is there any performance difference for time in above w.r.t `map` & `inject`  for above case ?

Comment: I don't know about the difference in performance. My guess is that it would be minimal. The main thing, as I see it, is that it would be easier for the reader (and maybe you, in a few months) to understand what you are doing if you were to use `map`. Having `map` on the outside immediately tells the reader that you are merely transforming each element of the receiver, rather than doing something more complex with those elements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I got it, checked your answer's explanation also!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def remove_student_ids(arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |value, index| 
   arr[index] = 'X' if @student_ids.include?(value) }
  end
end

array1.map{ |sub_arr| remove_student_ids(sub_arr)}
```